# how to load data from database in java through hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, session

I am writing a java project. and I use hibernate as ORM . now I build and filled my database using hibernate. the question is how can I load records from database and make objects from them?

Comment: -1. You read the Hibernate manual and perhaps go through some example programs to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 3):

That is the first step on any Hibernate Tutorial available online:
[here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm)